# GeoPandas plot does not work

Tags: python, geopandas, matplotlib

I am running this code

```
import geopandas
df = geopandas.read_file('test.geojson')
ax = df.plot(figsize=(10, 10), alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
```

and I get nothing besides this error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py:197: Warning: Source ID 8 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._idle_draw_id)
```

The GeoJSON is okay, I tested it in QGIS. The same error turns up if I try it with other geofiles.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you import `matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and add `plt.show()` to the end of the script, the error disappears and the plot is shown.